# Angular move directive from div to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-layout

I have problem in my project I have something like this:

```
<div class="ui-layout-center">
    <left></left>
    <right></right>
    <div class="container-to-max"></div>
  </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/deBMT5DAaoU47t4RxDhK?p=preview

in right pane I have few nesting directive and last directive have option to maximalize I need maximalize this directive in central pane, probably I would like fill the empty div parent div hide. I need something like this because I have in directive I have data what I need display and jquery plugin and so on. but I no have idea how do it could someone help me?

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're trying to do. What exactly do you mean by maximalize? Do you mean maximize?

Comment: when I click to maximalize I need something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/u4IkuTGYcEqX9ONCsbZD?p=preview

Comment: So, you actually need an animation?

Comment: no I actually need way how copy this directive to that div :) In first Plnkr I have empty div with class container-to-max that is target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understood, you can get access to any element inside your directive via elm params. Here it is.

```
`http://plnkr.co/edit/IhwysGj8gq2If01CoxP7?p=preview`
```